# Mercurial - meaning of tokens?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

Please see the attached image (courtesy [HgInit's Mercurial tutorial](http://hginit.com)).

[image]

What does it mean by

1. --- a
2. +++ b
3. @@  -1,4  +1,4 @@

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--- a/guac` - the outgoing file (the first version to be compared), in this case, since it is about two versions of the same file, a *virtual* path prefix `a/` is prefixed, even when it doesn't exist actually

`+++ b/guac` - the incoming file (the second version to be compared)

`@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@` - the outgoing and incoming line ranges, meaning in this case `-1,4` the outgoing/original/first version refers to line `1` and `4` following lines, while `+1,4` the incoming/new/second version refers to the same range. Meaning that you'll end up with the same amount of lines (after taking out those with `-` prefix and putting in those with `+` prefix, in the rest of the diff chunk)